# How to send simulated data to Azure Application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I know Application insights can use to monitor the Web applications on azure platform. We just need to setup the Instrumentation id and account id.

But my requirement is to send the simulated data to Azure Application insights directly and show the graphs on dashboard. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: You can use sdk to collect/send telemetry.. compose the components you want & send it..

Comment: Bit old but start reading http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/

Answer (score 0):

Java sdk to send the simulated data onto Application insights.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/sample